# How to package only the dist folder in a monorepo

Tags: lerna, yarn-workspaces, npm-publish

I am using lerna and yarn workspaces in my monorepo. The package structure looks like this:

```
root
`--- packages
     |--- pkg1
     |    |--- src
     |    |    `--- index.ts
     |    `--- dist
     |         `--- index.js
     `--- pkg2
          |--- src
          |    `--- index.ts
          `--- dist
               `--- index.js
```

- `src` folder gets compiled into `dist` folder.
- From each package, I would like to publish only the `dist` folder so that the imports work without the need of a `main` entry in package.json pointing inside the `dist` folder. This is easy to do with lerna: `lerna publish --contents dist`.

This works fine for external projects needing to use this repo, however it doesn't work within the repo itself. For example, if `pkg2`, depends on `pkg1`, it looks for pkg1's index.js file at `pkg1/index.js` while in reality the compiled version is sitting under `pkg1/dist/index.js`. How can I make this work?

P.S. I have seen this work in repositories like [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui), but I can't explain how it works there!

Comment: Did you found a solution?
Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568475/lerna-typescript-npm-how-do-i-properly-setup-the-config-so-that-projectnam?noredirect=1#comment109670510_61568475

Comment: No, I haven't found a good solution yet. Also looked at the SO question you pointed to.

Comment: I spent most of this afternoon migrating it to https://nx.dev/, it works very well, but I just hit a build bug.

Comment: It's not the solution I wanted, but what I did was set the `outDir` to `'./'` in `tsconfig.json`. This way the transpiled files are all dumped in the root folder and I can reference them without `/dist/...`.

Answer (score 10):

Finally got the solution:

You need to add publishConfig in the package.json of the dependency to be injected, refer following:

[image]

EDIT: Please find the code below:

```
{
  "name": "@name/shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shared dependencies for react-native and reactJs",
  "main": "dist/index",
  "types": "dist/index",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "directory": "dist"
  },
```

Cheers

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I have no clue how you found out about this but that's wonderful

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "files" field of package.json file https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files

> The "files" field is an array of files to include in your project. If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files inside that folder. (Unless they would be ignored by another rule.)

Comment: This is ignoring `index.d.ts` inside `dist` for me